# UITableViewCell "full" swipe, right-to-left

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I have a UITableView with cells already implementing two custom buttons (UITableViewRowAction edit actions) when swiping right-to-left.  All works well.

I'd like to trigger one of the buttons' actions when the user swipes "all the way" (also right-to-left), similar to Mail.app.

Code is Swift 3, for iOS 9 and 10.

I have what I believe to be sufficient code in place.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .delete
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("commit editingStyle")
}
```

The `commit editingStyle` function never fires, as I would expect it to.

I removed my `editActionsForRowAt` method, thinking perhaps I was screwing something up while defining the custom buttons.  I now see the default "Delete" button, but `commit editingStyle` still does not fire.

For what it's worth, this is a UITableView inside a UIViewController (not a UITableViewController), with both .dataSource and .delegate set to the class in question.  It is also a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Comment: For what it's worth, even the Master/Detail template project (Xcode 8.3.2) has these methods and doesn't support full swiping.  Perhaps the stuff I'm reading, suggesting right-to-left full swiping is built-in, is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Add this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Already in place - I should have included that in my original question.  This function is being called as expected.  (It's being called three times for a single swipe, for whatever that's worth.)

Answer (score 0):

Attach a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the table itself, not to the individual cells. When a swipe is detected, calculate which cell was swiped, and call your swipe action accordingly.

Comment: I thought about that, but it feels like the kind of hack I'd rather avoid.  I believe `commit editingStyle` exists for this purpose so I'm hoping to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a mechanism to do this, which I don't think is *too much* of a hack - certainly less-so than other solutions I found.  Comments are welcome.

My intent is always to use as much standard functionality as possible.  What I'm doing is to track how far a user has swiped the main body of the cell to the left.  When some threshold is reached, I tell the UITableView to perform the same action called from editActionsForRowAt for the button in question.

I'm using -225 as the threshold for how far to the left the cell has been moved.  This might not work for all implementations (and I may modify myself with more testing).  In my case I have two custom actions, the button for one is somewhat on the wide side.

The only thing I really add is an NSTimer, which I add to the main run loop using the .UITrackingRunLoopMode.  This has the benefit of running when (and only when) the user is moving their finger around.  When the timer fires, I check to see where the cell is relative to the host tableView.  No added views, no added gesture recognizers.

In the custom UITableViewCell, I added this:

```
var trackTimer:Timer? = nil
weak var tableView:StudentsLessonsViewController? = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupTimer()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    setupTimer()
}

func setupTimer() {
    self.trackTimer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(performActionIfScrolledFarEnough), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    if let trackTimer = self.trackTimer {
        RunLoop.main.add(trackTimer, forMode: .UITrackingRunLoopMode)
    }
}

func performActionIfScrolledFarEnough() {
    let globalPoint = self.superview?.convert(self.frame.origin, to: self.tableView?.tableView)
    //print("globalPoint.x: \(String(describing: globalPoint?.x))")
    if let globalPoint = globalPoint {
        if globalPoint.x < CGFloat(-225) {
            //print ("Perform Action NOW!!!")
            trackTimer?.invalidate()
            if let tableView = self.tableView {
                tableView.primaryActionButtonPressed(cell: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath, I added:

```
cell?.tableView = self
```

I already had this function in my UITableView, which I was calling when the user taps one of the buttons defined in editActionsForRowAt:

```
func tableView.primaryActionButtonPressed(cell:UITableViewCell)
```

In my primaryActionButtonPressed function I remove the cell from the tableView (conceptually like a delete).  It's possible dissimilar actions might require different implementation details.